# What is the difference between href="//..." and href="https://..."

Tags: html, http, cdn

I often see `href="//any.cdn.com"` and ask me if there's a difference or benefit to use this notation over `href="https://any.cdn.com"`?

Comment: the first will inherit the protocol being served by your site (are you using http, https, etc.), the latter is explicit.

Comment: @Napoli you saved rwx from my trigger finger! Now post that as an answer!

Comment: @GrantGarrison they should have a merciful badge

Comment: @Napoli lol. I have a personal FireAlarm, so I kind of listen to that a lot. This question triggered it, so I was about to downvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first will inherit the scheme being served by your site (are you using http, https, etc.), the latter is explicit.

More information can be found here https://jeremywagner.me/blog/stop-using-the-protocol-relative-url/